# Convergence of sequence of function $\frac{|x|^n}{n+|x|^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequence-of-function

When does this sequence of functions converges uniformly: 
$$f_n(x)=\frac{|x|^n}{n+|x|^n}$$

As I observed, this sequence converges to $0$ pointwise in $[-1,1]$ but I am unable to tackle the case for uniform convergence.

Comment: It doesn't converge to zero everywhere, and it doesn't converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Is the limit function continuous at $1$?

Comment: It converges in [-1,1]

Comment: @MarkViola Yes, it is continuous.

Comment: How can it be continuous, the limit function is $1_{[-1,1]^c}$?

Comment: Sorry, but I am unable to see how the limit function is $1 $ in the complement.

Comment: @XYZABC copper.hat has explained why in his answer.

Comment: @xyzabc No, the limit function is not continuous at $1$ and cannot be uniformly convergent on the reals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could note that if $|x| \le 1$ then $|f_n(x)| \le {1 \over n}$?

If $|x| >1$ then $f_n(x) = {1 \over 1+{n \over |x|^n}}$, so $f_n(x) \to 1$, but the convergence is not uniform.

Note that $f_n({\sqrt[n]{n}}) = {1 \over 2}$ for all $n$.

Comment: But what if $|x|>1$.

Comment: $f_n\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n}} \right)=\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{n+1/n}=\frac{1}{1+n^2}$

Comment: I had a small mistake. Fixed now. However, it would behoove you to actually look for such examples yourself.

Comment: Okay, but still I am unable to see $f_n({\sqrt[n]{n}}) = {1 \over 2}$.

Comment: $(\sqrt[n]{n})^n = n$ and ${ n \over n+n} = {1 \over 2}$????

Comment: Okay, sorry I was mistaken. It was $(\sqrt[n]{n})^n $. I am really sorry.